# How can I get the amount of step counts using healthkit in Ionic ios platform?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, healthkit

I have added `$cordovaHealthKit`, done all necessary **permission** steps, Now, how can I get only the amount of total step count using healthkit in Ionic platform?

The code below is defined under `$ionicPlatform.ready` for permission,

```
$cordovaHealthKit.isAvailable().then(function(yes) {
// HK is available
var permissions = ['HKWorkoutActivityTypeWalking'];

$cordovaHealthKit.requestAuthorization(
    permissions, // Read permission
    [] // Write permission
    ).then(function(success) {
   }, function(err) {
  });

 },   function(no) {
});
```

Comment: can you please provide the steps and blog or links that you followed i am also stuggling in this topic help

Comment: @MohanGopi https://devdactic.com/healthkit-app-with-ionic/ I followed this blog, however I managed to receive the JSON data same as tutorial but it has no property like "step counts", I used activityType 'Walking'

Comment: that tutorial work only on ios is it possible for you to provide me an android tutorial because i dont have a mac system with me